# unhashable type: 'SimpleTZ' when loading GPS data into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, gis

I've been parsing some GPS tracks in R, and thought I'd try the same thing in Python, even though my Python skills are a lot weaker.

I'm working through https://towardsdatascience.com/how-tracking-apps-analyse-your-gps-data-a-hands-on-tutorial-in-python-756d4db6715d

Everything is going well up until

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lon', 'lat', 'alt', 'time'])
for point in data:
    df = df.append({'lon': point.longitude, 'lat' : point.latitude, 'alt' : point.elevation, 'time' : point.time}, ignore_index=True)
```

which gives me an error that ends with

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'SimpleTZ'

One GPS point looks like this:

`GPXTrackPoint(40.08285088, -75.19106663, elevation=144.4, time=datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 22, 18, 36, 41, tzinfo=SimpleTZ("Z")))`

I'm using Python  3.7.0 in Jupyter via Anaconda on Windows.

I'd prefer to parse the timestamp with the zone, but am willing to discard the zone if that makes things much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I get the sense that this is more of a pandas problem than a gpxpy problem. Or even a general timezone problem?

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23682
- https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/792

In any case, this slightly different approach from https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/08/18/gpx/ does work

```
data = []
gpx = gpxpy.parse(open(gpxfile))
track = gpx.tracks[0]
segment = track.segments[0]

for point_idx, point in enumerate(segment.points):
    data.append([point.longitude, point.latitude,
                 point.elevation, point.time, segment.get_speed(point_idx)])

columns = ['Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Altitude', 'Time', 'Speed']
df = DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```